# Extracting rows from original data frame based on condition to create new data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, conditional-statements

Given a data frame, I am interested in extracting rows with IDs that match IDs in a given list and turning these rows into a new data frame.

Example:

ids_list=[123, 345, 567, 789, 234, 456, 678]

oringal_df

| ids | grade | major |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 98 | Engineering |
| 345 | 100 | English |
| 111 | 64 | History |
| 456 | 85 | Drama |
| 444 | 75 | Math |

new_df is created with rows where oringal_df[ids] is in ids_list

| ids | grade | major |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 98 | Engineering |
| 345 | 100 | English |
| 456 | 85 | Drama |

I wrote the following and I have tried other variations but I keep getting errors. Please help.

```
for i in original_df.loc[original_df['ids']]:
    if original_df[i].isin(ids_list):
        data=original_df.loc[original_df[i]]
        new_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is better:

```
new_df = df.loc[df['ids'].isin(ids_list)]
print(new_df)
```

output:

```
   ids  grade        major
0  123     98  Engineering
1  345    100      English
3  456     85        Drama
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I must have missed a step earlier because I thought I tried this but when I did it only True and False appeared in the new table.